# Jquery and validation popup options

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

Thanks for taking the time to read this, my question is in regards to how jquery does the validation errors, I've noticed that if I put in code like so:

```
$("#MainForm").validate();
```

When the error is raised on submit, and it pops up a nice box with an arrow pointing to the field in question.
[image: simple validation]

When I use the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
    $("#MainForm").validate();
    });
```

[image: when I put it into the ready function]

I only get text saying that the field is required, instead of the nice little pop-up box.
I noticed this when I started adding rules, and frankly I would prefer the original popup, is there a way to tell jquery validation to use that method, instead of the text fields like in the second example?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Michael, the code is basically the same in both examples, are you sure it's no other code making the difference you refer to?

Comment: The difference is the first code example, calls validate, without being inside the ready function, whereas the second code is inside the ready function for the document.  If I call it, it works fairly well, but if I add rules and etc, it only works correctly inside the ready function.

Comment: I get the feeling that the script for "pops up a nice box" is after the .validate code, also inside the .ready function. Can you check thru the functions/code being run in the .ready function. The .validate there should be the last in the line.

Comment: Not really, I mean what you see there is what it is, I can grab the screen shots I made, see if that clarifies the issue better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *pop up nice box* is generated by Internet Explorer, and not by jQuery Validation, when you add `required` attribute. jQuery Validation is not binded yet to your input element. Try to remove `$("#MainForm").validate();` , reload page, and re-submit your form. The result will be the *pop up nice box*.

As far as I know, the only way to tell jQuery Validation to use that method is by customize css files used within jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: OK, That answers that, I had wondered if it was somehow a browser and not a jQuery situation;)  I did notice that each browser (Chrome, Firefox and IE) had a different box.  Thanks for your answer!